# How to compare the high & low of multiple historic candles?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am looking to find out how to compare hisotric candles `High - Low` against one another.

Ex:

1. Find the Value `High - Low` of the **past X candles** | X being adjustable value.
2. Save the values for each candle.
3. Find the **Greatest Value** candle in the sequence.

The main problem is making how far we lookback adjustable and also comparing the multiple values to find the greatest value.

For lookingback at histroic price it's possible to manually compare each and every candle

```
candle1 = high[1] - low[1]
candle2 = high[2] - low[2]
candle3 = high[3] - low[3]
```

**And so On.**

However we can not adjust how many historical candles to compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ta.highest()` for that. Simply pass your condition and length to it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

len = 5
src = (high - low)

highest_range = ta.highest(src, len)

label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(src), color=color.new(color.black, 100), textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down)
label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(highest_range), color=color.new(color.black, 100), textcolor=color.green, style=label.style_label_up)
```

The white labels above the candles display that candle's range (`high - low`). The green labels below the candles display the highest range within the last X bars (5 in this example).

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much! This is not quite what I'm looking for. I am looking to find a candles Total size [Wick to Wick], not the "highest" or "lowest" point out of X amount of candles. We than want to compare the past X amount of candles "Sizes [Wick to Wick / High to Low]" to find the largest candle in the the X range.